# Commit via SVN and Client certificate

Tags: svn

Is there a way to commit code via SVN without SVN asking for a 'Client certificate filename' all the time?

Comment: What SVN client and server are you using? I use both AnkhSVN, TortoiseSVN and the command line SVN clients and non of those ask for a Client certificate filename when used against either local filesystem or remote svnserv-server with sasl.

Comment: I use SVN from Linux

$ svn --version
svn, version 1.4.4 (r25188)
   compiled Jun 29 2007, 22:43:46

Answer (score 11):

In your client you should be able to configure the path to the client certificate, see [the subversion docs](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html#svn.serverconfig.httpd.authn)

```
[examplehost]
ssl-client-cert-file = /path/to/my/cert.p12
ssl-client-cert-password = somepassword
```

Comment: Thanks!  I don't think I will use the ssl-client-cert-password because I would not want a password displayed in plain-text unless there is a way to store it encrypted.

Comment: This needs to be put into the file `servers` in the Subversion application setting directory. (see page 3 of http://svn.cacert.org/CAcert/Sysadm/client-certificate-guide.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

At Ubuntu I had to add the following lines at the ~/.subversion/servers file:

```
[groups]
cacert = hostname
[cacert]
ssl-client-cert-file = /path/to/my/cert.p12
ssl-client-cert-password = somepassword
```

Without using [groups] and directly having the hostname (eg *.example.com), it did not work for me.

At [svn advanced confarea](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.confarea.html), it states:

> The servers file contains Subversion configuration options related to the network layers. There are two special sections in this file—[groups] and [global]. The [groups] section is essentially a cross-reference table. The keys in this section are the names of other sections in the file; their values are globs—textual tokens that possibly contain wildcard characters—that are compared against the hostnames of the machine to which Subversion requests are sent.
>
> When Subversion is used over a network, it attempts to match the name of the server it is trying to reach with a group name under the [groups] section. If a match is made, Subversion then looks for a section in the servers file whose name is the matched group's name. From that section, it reads the actual network configuration settings.